# How to use the WXPrerenderManager in weex?

Tags: weex

I saw Weex's Playground demo use some `WXPrerenderManager`'s methods when rendering WXSDKInstance.

```
_instance = [[WXSDKInstance alloc] init];
if([WXPrerenderManager isTaskExist:[self.url absoluteString]]){
    _instance = [WXPrerenderManager instanceFromUrl:self.url.absoluteString];
}
```

But I didn't find the code adding prerender task to `WXPrerenderManager`.

When looking into `isTaskExist` method, it seems to be used with a `configCenter`.

So, how to use `WXPrerenderManager` correctly to pre-render some weex pages?

Answer (score 0):

This is an experimental feature and not been released.

Now only in iOS, the pre-render can works. In Android, only sync and fixed elements can be pre-rendered.